# Angular 4 Issue with ngIf

Tags: html, angular, onclick, materialize, angular4-forms

I am having a search icon and a search bar in a component template.
Following is the HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle search" id="search">
  <span class="menu-label"></span>
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large" (click)="toggleSearchBar()">
    <i class="large material-icons">search</i>
  </a>
  <ul *ngIf="showSearchBar">
    <li class="waves-effect waves-light" id="search_form">
      <form>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input id="search" name='filter'type="search">
          <label class="label-icon" for="search">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
          </label>
          <span class="close_btn" (click)="toggleSearchBar()">
            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the component I have a function that just toggles out the variable:

```
  toggleSearchBar() {
    this.showSearchBar = !this.showSearchBar;
  }
```

Question : on click of the span with close_btn class, the search input text completely goes away. Even If I click the search icon. I tried debugging and checking the boolean does change. But in the view the input text box doesn't appear. Have tried the detectchanges as well.
What could be possibly wrong ?

Comment: Have you initialized your variable. Try to assign `false`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan yes

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyf4jh - it works as expected ?

Comment: @Vega  It does work in your code because of unapplied css rules.

Comment: It doesn't work in my application probably due to some css getting applied to it .Btw I'm using materialise css. @Vega

Comment: I had to make it work using a ngClass

`[ngClass]="{'active': !showSearchBar}" ` on the outermost div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with 
`[ngClass]="{'active': !showSearchBar}"`